# Prettier adding semicolon when semi: false

Tags: javascript, reactjs, prettier

I have a react component with this jsx

```
  {posts?.map((post) => {
    <Post key={post.id} post={post} />
  })}
```

When I save the file prettier automatically adds a semicolon infront of <Post ... />.  This is causing the component to fail to render.

I have the semi option set to false.

Comment: The component will not render anything there anyway since you're not returning

Comment: Have you tried removing the `{}` on your map callback? Seems like that is the issue.

Comment: Not exactly sure why it affects the `no-semi` option, but I suspect that the formatter recognizes that your callback is in the shape of `() => {codeblock}` and expects it to have a `return` statement, which you did not, and maybe that's where the issue occurs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is happening because currently your map function is not returning anything

`<Post key={post.id} post={post} />` needs to be returned by map just like you return jsx inside your react component.

If you want to keep the one line and not explicitly return, change your curly braces to parenthesis to return your jsx

```
 {posts?.map((post) => (
    <Post key={post.id} post={post} />
  ))}
```

which is the same as

```
{posts?.map((post) => {
      return <Post key={post.id} post={post} />;
    })}
```